# pytest running scenarios in the correct order in the class

Tags: python, pytest

So I have the following structure:

```
class Test(object):

   def test_1(self):
      pass

   def test_2(self):
      pass

   def test_3(self):
      pass
```

it runs great, NOW I'm adding the "scenarios" (as it's recommended at [pytest - A quick port of “testscenarios”](http://pytest.org/latest/example/parametrize.html#a-quick-port-of-testscenarios)):

```
def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    idlist = []
    argvalues = []
    for scenario in metafunc.cls.scenarios:
        idlist.append(scenario[0])
        items = scenario[1].items()
        argnames = [x[0] for x in items]
        argvalues.append(([x[1] for x in items]))
    metafunc.parametrize(argnames, argvalues, ids=idlist)

class Test(object):
       scenarios = ['1' {'arg':'value1'},
                    '2' {'arg':'value2'}]

       def test_1(self, arg):
          pass

       def test_2(self, arg):
          pass

       def test_3(self, arg):
          pass
```

When I run it the **ORDER of tests is wrong**, I get:

```
test_1[1]  
test_1[2]  
test_2[1]   
test_2[2]  
test_3[1]  
test_3[2]
```

Doesn't really look like a scenario for the Test class.

QUESTION: Is the any solution to run it in the correct order? like:

```
test_1[1]
test_2[1]
test_3[1]
test_1[2]
test_2[2]
test_3[2]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The upcoming pytest-2.3 has support for better (resource-based) ordering, and i just updated the scenario example in the docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/parametrize.html#a-quick-port-of-testscenarios

You can preliminary install the current development version with

```
pip install -i http://pypi.testrun.org -U pytest
```

and should get pytest-2.3.0.dev15 with "py.test --version" and be able to use it.

Answer (score 1):

`py.test` runs tests in a distributed fashion, which means the order is essentially random.

You should use the `-n` option and set the process number to `1`.
Then tests should be run in alphabetical order by the single process spawned.

More than this I don't know if you can do. Anyway depending on the order of tests is generally *bad* design. So you should try to not depend on it at all.

Comment: I think Alex was not referring to distributed testing here, otherwise i mostly agree.

Comment: @Bakuriu Thanks for your answer, however indeed I was referring to the order of tests within the same process. Also about the order dependency - in my opinion, it's very arguable: test Classes should be independent, however test methods within - are my test steps. I'm using pytest not for unit tests, but for UI automation with Selenium webdriver.

Comment: Latest py.test does not seem to support -n, any ideas?