# pytest 2.3 adding teardowns within the class

Tags: python, pytest

I'm researching new version of pytest (2.3) and getting very excited about the new functionality where you

> "can precisely control teardown by registering one or multiple
>   teardown functions as soon as they have performed some actions which
>   need undoing, eliminating the no need for a separate “teardown”
>   decorator"

from [here](http://pytest.org/dev/setup.html#setup-functions-or-xunit-on-steroids)

It's all pretty clear when it's used as function, but how to use it in the class?

```
class Test(object):

    @pytest.setup(scope='class')
    def stp(self):
        self.propty = "something"

    def test_something(self):
    ... # some code
    # need to add something to the teardown

    def test_something_else(self):
    ... # some code
    # need to add even more to the teardown
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I got it working by having a 'session'-wide funcarg `finalizer`:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope = "session")
def finalizer():
    return Finalizer()

class Finalizer(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.fin_funcs = []

    def add_fin_func(self, func):
        self.fin_funcs.append(func)

    def remove_fin_func(self, func):
        try:
            self.fin_funcs.remove(func)
        except:
            pass

    def execute(self):
        for func in reversed(self.fin_funcs): 
            func()
        self.fin_funcs = []     

class TestSomething(object):

    @classmethod
    @pytest.fixture(scope = "class", autouse = True)
    def setup(self, request, finalizer):

        self.finalizer = finalizer
        request.addfinalizer(self.finalizer.execute)
        self.finalizer.add_fin_func(lambda: some_teardown())

    def test_with_teardown(self):

        #some test
        self.finalizer.add_fin_func(self.additional_teardown)

    def additional_teardown(self):
        #additional teardown
```

Thanks @hpk42 for answering e-mails and helping me get the final version.

NOTE: together with [xfailing the rest of the steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12579625/1167879) and [improved scenarios](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12526270/1167879) this now makes a pretty good **Test-Step structure**

Comment: would make sense to update to the actual pytest-2.3 release and its API, i.e. use "pytest.fixture".

Comment: @hpk42 Definitely will once I have it tested and make sure it works :)

Comment: It is scary to see "self" in a class method as argument as opposed to "cls" even if it is just convention.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, there are no good examples for teardown yet.  The [request object](http://pytest.org/dev/funcargs.html#request) has a addfinalizer method.  Here is an example usage:

```
@pytest.setup(scope=...)
def mysetup(request):
     ...
     request.addfinalizer(finalizerfunction)
     ...
```

The finalizerfunction will be called when all tests withing the scope finished execution.

Comment: Yes, I've seen that `request.addfinalizer()`, but how to access `request` object in the class under test? btw, I like this `addfinalizer` idea, it has great potential.