# How do I install py.test-2.3?

Tags: python, testing, pip, pytest

I know this sounds strange but I can't get it. Here (http://pytest.org/dev/getting-started.html) 
it says that a simple `pip install pytest` would work, but that only installs pytest-2.2.4

I tried going to `pypi.python.org` and find it directly but all I get is pytest-2.2.4 (http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest)

Several google searches yielded no results except for the fact that it seems everyone has managed to get it except me.

Using Python27 on a Mac.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2.2.4 is the current release . . . 2.3 is a dev version

There are instructions to get the latest code here:

http://pytest.org/latest/develop.html

I believe this should work as well:

```
pip install -i http://pypi.testrun.org -U pytest
```

That's the answer from this question (and appears to be from the lead dev of pytest):  [pytest running scenarios in the correct order in the class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12521924/pytest-running-scenarios-in-the-correct-order-in-the-class)

Comment: Ohh...why would they use 2.3 as the example for installing then? In their installation site, when verifying that you got the "correct version", they use `2.3.0.dev21` as the example. Very confusing.

Comment: @Nacht Note the URL you were using has `dev` in it.  You probably wanted latest:  http://pytest.org/latest/getting-started.html; the URLs with dev in them are the ones that are currently being worked on.

Answer (score 1):

pytest-2.3 has just been released, so you can get it by installing from pypi via e.g.

```
pip install -U pytest
```

It's true that the documentation was a bit confused - hopefully dev and latest will be more separate in the future. Note, btw, that the docs will see un-announced extra-released which have a version number like "2.3.0.N" which means that docs got updated but no code changed.